# Make second tkinter widget popup after running code

Tags: python, tkinter

Heres where i got stuck :

```
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, width = 50)
l = Label(root, text = 'Enter your phone number')
l.pack()
e.pack()
def myClick():
    global a
    a = e.get()
    root.destroy()
myButton = Button(root, text = 'Enter', command = myClick)
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
def randomString(stringLength=3):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return 'hbgvfc' + ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\memet\Desktop\Projects\chromedriver')
def fillaccount1():
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-n-en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp')
    next = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountDetailsNext"]/span/span')
    name1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="firstName"]')
    name2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lastName"]')
    username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    password_confirm = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirm-passwd"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    name1.send_keys(randomString())
    name2.send_keys(randomString())
    username.send_keys(randomString())
    password.send_keys('nhbgvf')
    password_confirm.send_keys('bhgvfcd')
    next.click()
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    number = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phoneNumberId"]')
    next2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gradsIdvPhoneNext"]/span/span')
    number.send_keys(a)
    next2.click()
    code = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="code"]')
```

I want the widget to popup right after running the previous line of code, and then closing after receiving user input to run the next lines:

```
code.send_keys(c)
    next0 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gradsIdvVerifyNext"]/span/span')
    next0.click()
```

making a new popup using the same method for the first popup gives me a 'TclError: can't invoke “destroy” command: application has been destroyed' error. is there any way to make the second window popup just like the first one ?

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def myClick():` method destroys the root window (`root.destroy()`). This is why you cannot have the second window displayed. You need to keep the root active (or create a new one).